# what happens when two stateful beans extends a single remote interface

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

which Stateless bean instance assigned to EJB object to serve the client, when two Stateless beans implements single remote interface and with same name

Ex:

```
@Stateless(name="KING")
public class One implements RemoteInterface{

}

@Stateless(name="KING")
public class Two implements RemoteInterface{

}
```

Comment: try it? I'd expect an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you will likely to get [`CreateException`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/ejb/CreateException.html) or [`NameAlreadyBoundException`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/naming/NameAlreadyBoundException.html), not sure though. Try it out, why not?

Comment: I have tried before posting this question. But I not getting any exception and always getting instance of same bean.

Comment: Show us the code. How you are trying to get that? and instance of which bean?

Comment: Yes, I have got an Exception stating that name is already bound. Previously I was using JBOSS 4.2.2, which was not throwing any exception. Now, I have changed the server to JBOSS 4.2.3. Now I got the exception

Answer (score 0):

Probably one will override the other if it doesn't throw exception